# Recursion with Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, rxjs

I need to upload a n-ary tree using a REST API in my angular 2 project.
I have a service allowing me to add a node like so:

```
addNode(node: TreeNode, parentId: number): Observable<NodeJson>
```

Where TreeNode is an object:

```
{
  data: any,
  children: TreeNode[]
}
```

I need the id of the parent node to be able to add children, and this id is in the NodeJson object.

My current solution is:

```
uploadTreeNode(node: TreeNode, parentId: number) {
    this.node_service.addNode(node, parentId)
        .subscribe(uploaded_node => {
            for (let child of node.children) {
                this.uploadTreeNode(child, uploaded_node.id)
            }
        }

}
```

Which works fine but here's my problem: I need to know when the whole tree
has been uploaded, which is not possible with this approach because I subscribe directly to the observable on each call and I have no way of knowing when it has completed.

Effectively, what I'm trying to achieve is having this function:

```
uploadNodeTree(node: TreeNode, parentId: number): Observable<NodeJson>
```

Which return an Observable that emits once all the Observables from the children uploads have completed.

Is there a way to do such thing with Rxjs operators ?

Comment: You can use `forkJoin` to know when all observables have emitted.

Comment: Yes but forkJoin takes a list of Observables as an argument, but I don't see how to build this list since i don't keep track of the Observables I subscribe to.

Comment: you might want to utilize `expand` operator. So, for as long as your observable returns node with parent, you use `expand` operator to call the whole function again. ref: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/expand.html

Comment: I don't think you want to subscribe for a start, cuz then your function will return a Subscription and not an Observable.

Comment: @deezg expand seems like a good solution, but as you said i'll need a function that return each node and its parent id, and this is where I'm stuck, since I have several child on each node I can't find a way to make such a function work

Comment: @Chrillewoodz You are right, that's exactly my problem, but if i don't subscribe I can't get the id form the parent since it's in an Observable

Comment: You can use the `tap` operator for that, as long as you use some `.subscribe` call higher up along with `forkJoin` for example. Or else your Observables won't run at all.

Comment: you need just one `subscribe`, that's the point of `expand`. take a look at this example...its not the same but it might give you an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529232/angular-2-http-observables-and-recursive-requests

Comment: @deezg Pardon me if I'm being retarded but expand seems appropriate when the recursion only operate on 1 item (feel free to let me know if I don't make sense), most example I find are about paging, where the stream emits a link to the next page, then the process is trivial: get the link and make the request with it in a function passed to expand and the result of this function will be merged into the initial stream. But my brains melts over the for loop in my function, I don't see any way of applying expand for each child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out, `expand` is right operator. The solution is to upload the 1st node and use `expand` to create a stream of requests from its children and "append it" to the source stream, once there are no more children, just send empty() to end the stream:

```
uploadTreeNode(node: TreeNode): Observabe<NodeJson> {
    return this.node_service.addNode(node, rootId)
        .map(uploaded_node => ({id: uploaded_node.id, current_node: node})
        .expand({id, current_node} => {
            if (current_node && current_node.children) {
                let reqs = current_node.children.map(n => this.nodeService.addNode(id, n))
                return Observable.merge(...reqs)
            } else {
                return Observable.empty()
            }
        })   
}
```

Now I can do :

```
this.uploadTreeNode(myNode, 1).subscribe(uploaded_node => {
    console.log('Node has been uploaded: ' + uploaded_node),
})
```

Thanks for your help everyone.