# How can I get data from all pages of my REST API?

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

I have implemented a search engine in my application and I need to obtain all the data I have of a resource, for example all the posts of a user.

My api returns the following for example:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/resource/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "resource_data": "data"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to make a method in my service that returns a promise with an array that contains the data of all the pages.

My knowledge about typescript or javascript is limited and I can't find a way to do it elegantly.

### The solution:

Using the selected answer as the best I have developed this code that goes into my service

```
    getAllMDPosts(): Observable<MDPost[]> {
        return this.getRecursivelyMDPosts(`${environment.apiUrl}/mdposts/`);
    }

    private getRecursivelyMDPosts(url: string, results?: MDPost[]): Observable<MDPost[]> {
        if (results === undefined) {
            results = [];
        }
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
            switchMap(response => {
                    if (response.next) {
                        return this.getRecursivelyMDPosts(response.next, results.concat(response.results));
                    } else {
                        return of(results.concat(response.results));
                    }
            })
        );
    }
```

*I am not a fan of ternary operators, I usually add more code to conditionals and I have to modify ternary operators.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Http, Observables and recursive requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529232/angular-2-http-observables-and-recursive-requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to switch map to the next page until there is no more pages

```
getData(url: string, results?: dataType[]): Observable<dataType[]> {
   return this.http.get(url).pipe(
     switchMap(response) {
       return response.next ?
         this.getData(response.next, [...results, ...response.results]) : // Get the next page
         of([...results, ...response.results]) // Just return the results
     }
   )
}
```

and make the first call with no results

```
this.yourService.getData('http://127.0.0.1:8000/resource/').subscribe(finalResults => {
  // do stuff with results
});
```

Comment: Very good answer, just what we need. I have made some modifications to make it work and adapt it better.
I put my code in the question.